# Связанные стили в Scene Builder не найдены во время выполнения

Tags: css, javafx, scene-builder

Я создаю панель в `Scene Builder` для `Java 8`. Мои файлы `.css` хранятся в `/rescouces/css/app.css`. Я соединяю таблицу стилей в `Scene Builder` и все в порядке. Но после того, как я запустил приложение, я получаю исключение с ошибкой: `Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Invalid resource: /../style/app.css not found on the classpath`

Как это исправить? Мне нужно каждый раз переименовать путь в `css` в `.fxml`?

Comment: установите нормальный путь в самом файле. `/` указывает, что поиск начнется с корня ресурсной папки, и тут вы сразу из корневой папки поднимаетесь на уровень вверх, как-то это не очень правильно.

Comment: @Maxim в том то и дело. Что у `SceneBuilder`-а корень считает то где открыли `fxml`, а не корень папки `resources`. Если я перемещу `fxml` в корень ресурсов, то все по идее должно быть норм. Но я хочу сохранить структуру нормальную.

Comment: Опечатка в `/rescoUCes/css/app.css` не может быть причиной?

Comment: @AndreyM это тут я сам писал. опечатался. там пути верные.